# Airpods with SpeechRecognizer is not working

Tags: swift, avfoundation, speech-to-text, avaudiosession, avkit

Is there an option to connect headphones to the phone with SFSpeechRecognizer enabled?

I am trying to build an application. in that mono will use a speech recognizer for text with the headphones turned on.

I have gone through a lot of links about problems with connecting headphones to the phone due to AVAudioeSession configurations, and it seems that I have tried everything

This is how my configs are

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .videoChat, options: [.allowBluetoothA2DP, .defaultToSpeaker])
try audioSession.setActive(true)
```

I found a small preset description for the type here: [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html)

Bluetooth is already known and present in options and much more, but we managed to connect sound through airpods

In fact, I would like the sound to be redirected to the airpods

[project example link from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/recognizing_speech_in_live_audio)